# Calculate average and class-wise precision/recall for multiple classes in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a multiclass model with 4 classes. I have already implemented a callback able to calculate the precision/recall for each class and their macro average. But for some technical reason, I have to calculate them using the metrics mechanism.

I'm using TensorFlow 2 and Keras 2.3.0. I have already used the `tensorflow.keras.metrics.Recall/Precision` to get the class-wise metrics:

```py
metrics_list = ['accuracy']
    metrics_list.extend([Recall(class_id=i, name="recall_{}".format(label_names[i])) for i in range(n_category)])
    metrics_list.extend([Precision(class_id=i, name="precision_{}".format(label_names[i])) for i in range(n_category)])

model = Model(...)
model.compile(...metrics=metrics_list)
```

However, this solution is not satisfying:

1. firstly, `tensorflow.keras.metrics.Recall/Precision` uses a threshold to define the affiliation to a class, while it should use `argmax` to define the most probable class, if `class_id` is defined
2. Secondly, I have to create 2 new metrics that would calculate the average over all classes, which itself requires to calculate the class-wise metrics. This is inelegant and inefficient to calculate twice the same thing.

Is there a way to create a class or a function that would calculate directly the class-wise and the average predicion/recall using the TensorFlow/Keras metrics logic?

Apparently I can easily obtain the confusion matrix using `tf.math.confusion_matrix()`. However, I do not see how to inject a list of scalar at once, instead of returning a single scalar.

Any comment is welcomed!

Comment: One possibility to overcome the first limitation, related to the threshold of ```tensorflow.keras.metrics.Recall/Precision```, is to convert the output probability vector into a 1-hot vector. For exemple, the CNN could issued 2 outputs, the probability vector and the 1-hot vector. Obviously, the 1-hot encoding would be based on ```argmax```.

Comment: To be a bit more clear, and after a careful reading of the documentation, TF applies a threshold on each element of the vector. For example, if the output vector is ```[0.54, 0.56, 0.58]```, with a threshold of 0.5, it will be evaluated as ```[1, 1, 1]``` and compared to the 1-hot vector ```[1, 0, 0]```. This is an issue for me when using the ```class_id``` option, as the ouput will be evaluated positive for class 0. In my case, I need to evaluate the ouput vector as ```[0, 0, 1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs that in my very specific case, I can simply use `CategoricalAccuracy()` as unique metric because i'm using a `batch_size=1`. It this case, `accuracy=recall=precision={1.|0.}` for a batch. That only partially solve the problem. The best solution would be to update the confusion matrix using `argmax` at each batch end, then calculate the Precision/Recall based on that. I don't known how it is possible to do that yet, but it should be doable.